# The best way to call a function inside another class? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, function, class, sprite-kit

So, I've got a fairly simple question regarding Classes and Functions in Swift.

Let's say I make an app with SpriteKit. I have a GameScene (SKScene), a GameViewController (UIViewController) and a main storyboard for the GameViewController.

If I wanted to have a button on top of my GameScene, I'd connect a button IBOutlet from the main storyboard to the GameViewController. But how can I set it up, so that if I touch the button I can call a function inside the GameScene?

Do I have to handle this with delegation or is there a simpler method?

EDIT:

To elaborate, the function I'd like to call is:

```
  func resetScene(){
        self.removeAllActions()
        self.removeAllChildren()
    }
```

I tried to declared as a `class func` but somehow it doesn't quite work.

Comment: you can declare your function globally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically four ways of calling a function from an other class.

1. Instance of the class. If you have an instance of say class *Object*, you can call *Object's* methods over that instance like **myObject.buttonTapped()**.
2. By delegation: Create a protocol for class A and declare the method in the protocol. Class A must have an instance of the protocol. Call that method in the **buttonTapped** method like **delegate.notifyButtonTapped()**. In class B, conform to the protocol and implement the **notifyButtonTapped()** method.
3. Notification: Post a notification over **NotificationCenter** from class A and addObserver to in class B for that notification. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) link for further information.
4. Closure/Blocks: In this case closure is not the best solution and they can be fairly complex to fully understand

You can go with the delegation here. Check [this link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns#delegation)  from rw for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the overview of possible solutions. I'll definitely check all of the methods out!

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Alessandro you are right. Will definetely do now on.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the way how you reset the `SKScene`, usually you can present the same scene to have a really cleaned scene, but I don't know your code so maybe I'm wrong.

About to how to access to the *viewController* of your scene you could find many ways as for example the *protocol/delegate* method but another one of them could be:

```
extension UIView {
    func getViewController<T: UIViewController>() -> T? {
        var responder = self.next
        while responder != nil {
            if let viewController = responder as? T {
                return viewController
            }
            responder = responder!.next
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And to use it :

```
if let gameVC = self.view?.getViewController(), gameVC is GameViewController {
    let vc = gameVC as! GameViewController
    print("That's all folks \(vc)")
}
```

Comment: Hey, quick question. I see now, how there are better ways to reset the scene. If I'd just present the scene again, would I have to remove the current scene first in some way or does it get handled automatically?

Comment: For instance, if I'd present the same scene again, would there be 2 scenes "on top of each other" or would the current scene be replaced by the latest called scene?

Comment: Answer to the first question: when you present the next scene, the current scene will be automatically deallocated so you don't have to remove the current scene.

Comment: Answer to the second question: there should be always 1 scene, if you can see two scene ( in memory allocation, using instruments) then you have made mistakes in your code like keep strong references of self in your scene

Comment: Is this a safe approach to reach the controller methods from a view? Is there any memory leaks or hard references or something? I'm new to swift and iOS dev...

Comment: @Sergio This isn't an approach to reaching functions of another view. This is SpriteKit, another framework, not UIKit: here we have a method to reach function of gameViewController from a scene (SKScene)

Comment: Ok. It did work in iOS though. I'm now looking for the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Making assumptions here, if your GameViewController contains a reference to your GameScene then you can do this quite easily. You can create an IBAction reference with a given method name `buttonTapped`. Inside this method you can then call a method on your GameScene that performs the actions you are looking to do

```
// GameViewController
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
   self.gameScene.reactionMethod()
}

// GameScene
public func reactionMethod() {
   // TODO: Do actions here
}
```

Comment: Getting error: `Value of type 'SKScene' has no member 'reactionMethod'`